# Golang web service not displaying in browser during local development in VSCode

Tags: go, http, server

I am currently working on a Golang web service using Visual Studio Code, and I'm encountering an issue where the server doesn't seem to display in my browser during local development

```
func barhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("foo"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/bar", barhandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
```

I've checked the following:

1. The server appears to be running without errors in the terminal.
2. I have configured the server to listen on a specific port (e.g., `http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)`).
3. I've tried accessing the server in my browser using the correct port (e.g., `http://localhost:5000`), but the page doesn't load.

I have also ensured that there are no errors in the browser console and that my firewall/antivirus is not blocking the connection. Despite these efforts, I'm unable to view the Golang web service in my browser.

Comment: Are you going to `http://localhost:5000` or `http://localhost:5000/bar`?

Comment: I tried http://localhost:5000/bar and my web service came up, thank you,  but then when I change the text and the url path nothing changes, is something wrong with my system P.S this just started happening

Comment: if you mean by "when you change the url path" is when you go to a different url, well, you only have a handler for `/bar`, so right now that is the only path this server will handle.  If you mean when you change it in the code, after each change to the code, you have to exit the server and rebuild, then run the newly compiled binary (or just `go run main.go` or whatever the file name is)